# xrandr did not detect external monitor

Tags: ubuntu, usb, monitor, xrandr

I'm trying to use an external monitor with a TypeC port on an Ubuntu20 system.
(previously the system was working well with HDMI port with another monitor)

The dell monitor shows "No USB TypeC Signal from Your Device".
and xrandr shows

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
P-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  48.02  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

So I guess the monitor is not detected?

Has tried re-install the Nvidia drive, not worked.

commented "options nvidia-drm modeset=1" in "/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf", not worked.

Thanks in advance